# how does this java code counts the number of things?

Tags: java, class, object, count

Dumb question but can someone explain to me why the code below counts the number of thing objects? i do not understand why the count method defined counts the number of objects? when does the iteration begin? any help with the clarification will be really appreciated

```
class Thing {
public String name;

    public static int count = 0;
    public Thing() {

        id = count;
        count++;
    }
    public void showName() {
        System.out.println("Object ID: " + id + ", " + description + ": " + name);
    }
}

public class Java_Static {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    // using count method
    System.out.println("Before creating objects, count is: " + Thing.count);

    // using variable
    Thing thing1 = new Thing();
    Thing thing2 = new Thing();

    thing1.name = "Abid";
    thing2.name = "Ruksaar";

    thing1.showName();
    thing2.showName();

    System.out.println("After creating objects, count is: " + Thing.count);

    


    

}
```

}

Comment: There is no count method, just a field that is basically a global variable that increments in the constructor.

Comment: Note that using modifiable class fields (rather than instance fields) is considered a code smell. Instead you could use a factory pattern where the factory keeps the count, for instance.

Comment: Every time you create a Thing object, the static variable Thing.count in increased.

Answer (score 1):

The integer `count` is a static field of the `Thing` class. This means that individual `Thing` objects do not have their own counts and only the class `Thing` stores the value of `count`. So whenever count is updated, as in the `Thing` constructor, the same variable is updated. This allows the `count` variable to store the number of `Thing` objects, as it is incremented by one each time a `Thing` is constructed.

Comment: Thank you, this kind of helps with my understanding, think it will take a bit of time to get my had around :)

Answer (score 1):

The Thing() method is called a constructor and it's fired every time and object is made from that class.

A method is recognised as a constructor when it has the same name as the class it's in.

So every time an object is made it runs the "Thing()" constructor which has "count++" which increments the count variable.

Comment: Thank you! so every time i create a new object of type Thing, the Thing constructor is ran and because the Thing constructor does a count, every time a Thing object is created, the count is incremented? - is this the reason why? or is there a gap in my knowledge?